# USB-powered 4G modem with ethernet port, WITHOUT WiFi

Tags: usb, router, ethernet, 4g

I'm looking for a reliable 4G modem with an RJ45 port (for a device I'd like to connect to the internet) that can be powered by USB (max 1amp, ideally) and doesn't have WiFi (or supports switching it off entirely).

So far all I can find is either [modems with ethernet ports that require 12v barrel power](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-LB2120-100UKS-Broadband-Connection-Automatic/dp/B0793JTXY3), or mini/micro USB powered [modems that offer only WiFi](https://www.amazon.co.uk/D-Link-Mbps-Wi-Fi-Hotspot-DWR-932/dp/B00OVJDCQ0/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=4g%20modem&qid=1613824710&s=computers&sr=1-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFNQVQ4RzM3SDhQTlomZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA4NTg4OTUzVFc0WUVKTUIwNkdYJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAxMDYwMTcyTTJQTDc5MUxMMkE5JndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==).

Currently my best options appear to be devices like these, or an RPi, plus a USB dongle 4G modem:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-Portable-Support-Configuration-Required/dp/B00634PLTW/ref=sr_1_21?dchild=1&keywords=4g+modem+ethernet&qid=1613824332&sr=8-21

https://www.amazon.co.uk/GL-iNet-GL-MT300N-V2-Converter-Pre-installed-Performance/dp/B073TSK26W/ref=sr_1_21?dchild=1&keywords=4g+modem+ethernet&qid=1613824332&sr=8-21

...but I'm hoping there's a reliable, affordable all-in-one device out there that meets my requirements with fewer points of failure. By "reliable", I mean something I can confidently leave in place for a year. By affordable, I mean < £100/$100. Reception strength needn't be more than an average phone's, and bandwidth / ping isn't terribly important either- it's for a low-bandwidth, low-power, always-on application.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're plugging in a computer to ethernet, you can already do that with most hotspots over USB.  Just disable wifi, plug it in, and install the drivers.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is just a gateway of sorts, without an operating system that would allow me to add drivers for anything. I appreciate that this is a bit of a niche request.